# Why would calling a dummy function fix a bug?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-8

I'm developing a project (in Java 8) that involves the simulation of logic circuits. The circuits are described in an input file that I'm parsing with ANTLR v4.

Using ANTLR's visitor classes, I build up a Composite structure that stores all of the necessary components to simulate the circuit.

```
// module is an ANTLR parse tree
BLXCircuit mainCircuit = modelGenerator.visit(module);
```

Afterwards, I initialize the inputs of this circuit to whatever the user specifies, but for simplicity, I will initialize them to false (assuming there are 3 inputs):

```
Map<BLXSocket, Boolean> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
List<BLXSocket> inputs = mainCircuit.getInputSockets();
valueMap.put(inputs.get(0), false);
valueMap.put(inputs.get(1), false);
valueMap.put(inputs.get(2), false);
```

and then I start the evaluator:

```
BLXEventManager eventManager = new BLXEventManager(valueMap, 500);
eventManager.start();
```

All of this works ***perfectly*** on Mac OS X, but when I run it on either Windows or Linux, the evaluation just... silently fails by returning incorrect values. The program exits gracefully, having output the wrong calculations.

However, and this is my question, if I define the functions:

```
private static void noAction(BLXSignalReceiver unused) { }
private static void whyDoesThisFixThings(BLXCircuit blxCircuit) {
    for (BLXSocket blxSocket : blxCircuit.getInputSockets()) {
        blxSocket.getTargets().forEach(Main::noAction);
    }
}
```

and add a call to this function just after the declaration of `mainCircuit`:

```
BLXCircuit mainCircuit = modelGenerator.visit(module);
whyDoesThisFixThings(mainCircuit); // why??
```

then both Windows and Linux will exhibit the correct behavior. Why could this possibly be?

**EDIT**: I have also discovered that this code operates differently (not better, necessarily) under a debugger than it does on its own.

**UPDATE**: I rewrote all of the code to run on Java 7 without changing its semantics. It now runs properly on JDK 7. The *exact* same code when running on Java 8 fails, too.

**UPDATE 2**: I was wrong before. It now seems that the program runs correctly only on *slow* machines. It works when it's run in a debugger or on the Macbook Air which has a slowish processor compared to the Core i7 in my development rig. This must be quite a race condition.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? (`java -version`) Are you compiling straight from `javac` or are you using Eclipse's (or some other IDE's) compiler?

Comment: Can you please post this question as a SSCE? We would like to be able to test it ourselves, and we cannot do that with your current code, nor are we interested in your classes if they do not matter to the execution itself.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) link just in case the OP doesn't know what it is.

Comment: They do matter to the execution... I'll try to come up with a short version of it, although that will be difficult since simulating circuits is non-trivial. In the meantime, the code is available publicly, though, at https://github.com/ddickstein/BooLeX. (see the `markfree` branch)

Comment: The version of java being used is `javac 1.8.0`. All of us are using IDEA to manage the compilation, but the compiler in use was downloaded straight from Oracle's website.

Comment: @AlexReinking Just a side note, but you might want to take a look at [Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). It's a tool designed specifically to create DSLs. Internally, it uses ANTLR.

Comment: We had a few constraints on the assignment (the staff will be testing our software and don't want to handle new frameworks), but I'll check it out!

Comment: My guess is that you change the order of initialization somehow.

Comment: It may be silly, but did you do a clean and build?

Comment: Yes, I did. I deleted all of the .class files manually (find + xargs rm) and rebuilt. I hoped it might be that, too.

Comment: `The program exits gracefully, having output the wrong calculations.` I am running your code on Linux. I tried it with and without the `whyDoesThisFixThings` call and I got the same output. What's the output / expected output you're getting?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey. The output I'm getting is posted here on PasteBin

http://pastebin.com/mbN7TRjA

Comment: @AlexReinking Odd. My incorrect output doesn't even match yours (my `carry` is `null`. http://pastebin.com/L0kUydTx. I won't be able to debug this issue until you come up with an SSCCE (that hopefully has the same behavior on my computer!) One thing you might want to do is take a look at the extra bytecode that's made for your no-op function and see what it's doing.

Comment: Any idea what could cause problems *like* this, though? I've tried with multiple versions/architectures of Java 8 and my output doesn't change...

Comment: It could be a Java 8 bug that hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: @WarrenDew Turns out you're right. See my update in the question. I'm not sure where the bug exists, but it's nasty, no doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks for all the help in the comments. Ultimately, this was a "race condition" (the program is single-threaded) in our evaluation model. We were using a priority queue without properly checking for duplicate, conflicting entries. For example, it was possible for conflicting signals to be sent to the same logic gate at undefined times.

This is probably the strangest bug I've encountered while writing Java code, at least in so far as how it presented itself.

Comment: Interesting. So, to clarify, it sounds like the issue is that the ordering among PriorityQueue elements of equal priority is undefined. Is that right?

Comment: @StuartMarks It seems to be defined that way in the javadoc: *The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily.*, on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: Right, my question is whether the simulator might have inadvertently relied on a particular ordering.

Comment: ^ It absolutely did. To simulate sequential circuits, we allowed a signal carrying the value of "null" to indicate "not ready". We ultimately added a stack to simulate stability, although we might end up implementing a more sophisticated data structure (or comparator) to more elegantly handle these broken cases.